# Add a number to class and update on each click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple anchor element with a class applied. Each time the anchor is clicked I would like to add a number to the class using jQuery, each additional click should increase this number by 1.

**Default Example:**

```
<a id="idname" class="classname" href="#">Next</a>
```

**1st Click:**

```
<a id="idname" class="classname1" href="#">Next</a>
```

**2nd Click:**

```
<a id="idname" class="classname2" href="#">Next</a>
```

And so on...

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions

Comment: I'm going way out on a limb here, but if you are manipulating class names in JavaScript rather than in CSS, you could use HTML5-valid data attributes; something like: $('#idname').click(function() { $(this).attr('data-clicked',$(this).attr('data-clicked')+1); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var className = "classname", count = 1;
$("a.classname").click(function(){
  this.className = (className + (++count));
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickCount = 0;
$("#idname").click(function(event) {
    $(this).removeClass(clickCount > 0 ? "classname" + clickCount : "className");
    clickCount++;
    $(this).addClass("classname" + clickCount); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
var count = 0;
$("#idname").click(function() {
    count++;
    $("#idname").attr('class', 'classname' + count) ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        className = $('#idname').attr('class');
        $('#idname').click(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            var counter = $this.attr('class').split(className)[1];              
            var nextNum = 1;
            if (counter != '') //if the counter has already started
                nextNum = parseInt(counter) + 1;
            $this.removeClass().addClass(className + nextNum);
        });
    });
```